# Regex Python Problems with MS

Tags: regex, python-3.x

i am a newbe to regex and cant find the solution. I have searched like 3 hours for a solution...

I have the text

> HELLO MS. I HOPE YOU HAVE NO PROBLEMS.

And i want to get the Result:

> HELLO MISTRESS I HOPE YOU HAVE NO PROBLEMS.

But my code replace also the "MS." from Problems.

```
re.sub(r'(MS)+[.]', 'MISTRESS', text)
```

Thanks for your help.

Using Python 3.5.

Comment: Use `(\bMS[.])` word boundaries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well an immediate fix here would be to place a lookbehind before `MS.` to assert that whitespace precedes:

```
text = "HELLO MS. I HOPE YOU HAVE NO PROBLEMS."
output = re.sub(r'(?<!\S)(MS)+[.]', 'MISTRESS', text)
print(output)
```

However, for a more general solution, we might need to better understand the grammar behind which contexts should be replaced and which should not.

Comment: @RichardZelzner Note that in this case you could also put a word boundary `\b` before `MS.` and it should also work.  My solution would work even in the first character of the target term were not a word character.

Answer (score 0):

Another way without `regex` using simple `replace()`,

```
dictionary = {"MR.":"MISTER", "MS.":"MISTRESS" } 
main_string = "HELLO MS. I HOPE YOU HAVE NO PROBLEMS WITH MR. X."
for key in dictionary.keys():
    main_string = main_string.replace(key, dictionary[key])
print(main_string)
```

Comment: reason for voting it down please